# How to minimize the latency involved in kafka messaging framework?

Tags: apache-kafka

**Scenario**: I have a low-volume topic (~150msgs/sec) for which we would like to have a
low propagation delay from producer to consumer.

I added a time stamp from a producer and read it at consumer to record the propagation delay, with default configurations the msg (of 20 bytes) showed a propagation delay of 1960ms to 1230ms. No network delay is involved since, I tried on a 1 producer and 1 simple consumer on the same machine.

When I have tried adjusting the topic flush interval to 20ms, it drops
to 1100ms to 980ms. Then I tried adjusting the consumers `"fetcher.backoff.ms"` to 10ms, it dropped to 1070ms - 860ms.

**Issue**: For a 20 bytes of a msg, I would like to have a propagation delay as low as possible and ~950ms is a higher figure.

**Question**: Anything I am missing out in configuration?
I do welcome comments, delay which you got as minimum.

**Assumption**: The Kafka system involves the disk I/O before the consumer get the msg from the producer and this goes with the hard disk RPM and so on..

---

**Update**:
Tried to tune the **Log Flush Policy** for Durability & Latency.
Following is the configuration:

```
# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
log.flush.interval=10
# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
log.default.flush.interval.ms=100
# The interval (in ms) at which logs are checked to see if they need to be 
# flushed to disk.
log.default.flush.scheduler.interval.ms=100
```

For the same msg of 20 bytes, the delay was 740ms -880ms.

The following statements are made clear in the configuration itself.
**There are a few important trade-offs:**

1. **Durability**: Unflushed data is at greater risk of loss in the event of a crash.
2. **Latency**: Data is not made available to consumers until it is flushed (which adds latency).
3. **Throughput**: The flush is generally the most expensive operation.

So, I believe there is no way to come down to a mark of 150ms - 250ms. (without hardware upgrade) .

Comment: Is there a constraint that you have to use Kafka? I ask because Kafka's strength is high-volume with both slow and fast consumers. The tradeoff is that its not as tunable as other messaging systems as far as latency.

Comment: what is the `fetch.message.max.bytes` in your consumer config ? did you try changing that to see if it has any impact? BTW which version of kafka you are using ?

Comment: @user2720864 Kafka-0.7.2 and cannot upgrade as of now since drivers are not available for Node.js and PHP

Comment: @PaulM: Mainly looking at Stream Processing. But, there is a need to handle messages without data loss. So main constraints are __durability and fault-tolerance__

Comment: does altering `fetch.message.max.bytes` helps ? might want to take a look [here](http://kafka.apache.org/08/ops.html) though it deals with the 0.8 version

Comment: @user2720864 I check with `message.max.bytes=1000000000000000` & `message.max.bytes=100` there is no noticeable change.

Comment: `message.max.bytes` is in the broker config , I was talking about the `fetch.message.max.bytes` available in the consumer config .. the default value is 1024*1024 .. it defines the amount of messages bytes it tries to fetch in a single attempt

Comment: @user2720864 my bad.. I tried `fetch.message.max.bytes=100` & `1000000` only not `message.max.bytes`

Comment: just a hint .. this appears to be less than the default value specified, you can try increasing the same to see if it helps consuming any faster .. from the doc it says `The fetch request size must be at least as large as the maximum message size the server allows or else it is possible for the producer to send messages larger than the consumer can fetch.`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I am not trying to dodge the question but I think that kafka is a poor choice for this use case. While I think Kafka is great (I have been a huge proponent of its use at my workplace), its strength is not low-latency. Its strengths are high producer throughput and support for both fast and slow consumers. While it does provide durability and fault tolerance, so do more general purpose systems like rabbitMQ. RabbitMQ also supports a variety of different clients including node.js. Where rabbitMQ falls short when compared to Kafka is when you are dealing with extremely high volumes (say 150K msg/s). At that point, Rabbit's approach to durability starts to fall apart and Kafka really stands out. The durability and fault tolerance capabilities of rabbit are more than capable at 20K msg/s (in my experience).

Also, to achieve such high throughput, Kafka deals with messages in batches. While the batches are small and their size is configurable, you can't make them too small without incurring a lot of overhead. Unfortunately, message batching makes low-latency very difficult. While you can tune various settings in Kafka, I wouldn't use Kafka for anything where latency needed to be consistently less than 1-2 seconds.

Also, Kafka 0.7.2 is not a good choice if you are launching a new application. All of the focus is on 0.8 now so you will be on your own if you run into problems and I definitely wouldn't expect any new features. For future stable releases, follow the link here [stable Kafka release](https://kafka.apache.org/downloads)

Again, I think Kafka is great for some very specific, though popular, use cases. At my workplace we use both Rabbit and Kafka. While that may seem gratuitous, they really are complimentary.

Answer (score 27):

I know it's been over a year since this question was asked, but I've just built up a Kafka cluster for dev purposes, and we're seeing <1ms latency from producer to consumer. My cluster consists of three VM nodes running on a cloud VM service (Skytap) with SAN storage, so it's far from ideal hardware. I'm using Kafka 0.9.0.0, which is new enough that I'm confident the asker was using something older. I have no experience with older versions, so you might get this performance increase simply from an upgrade.

I'm measuring latency by running a Java producer and consumer I wrote. Both run on the same machine, on a fourth VM in the same Skytap environment (to minimize network latency). The producer records the current time (`System.nanoTime()`), uses that value as the payload in an Avro message, and sends (acks=1). The consumer is configured to poll continuously with a 1ms timeout. When it receives a batch of messages, it records the current time (`System.nanoTime()` again), then subtracts the receive time from the send time to compute latency. When it has 100 messages, it computes the average of all 100 latencies and prints to stdout. Note that it's important to run the producer and consumer on the same machine so that there is no clock sync issue with the latency computation.

I've played quite a bit with the volume of messages generated by the producer. There is definitely a point where there are too many and latency starts to increase, but it's substantially higher than 150/sec. The occasional message takes as much as 20ms to deliver, but the vast majority are between 0.5ms and 1.5ms.

All of this was accomplished with Kafka 0.9's default configurations. I didn't have to do any tweaking. I used batch-size=1 for my initial tests, but I found later that it had no effect at low volume and imposed a significant limit on the peak volume before latencies started to increase.

It's important to note that when I run my producer and consumer on my local machine, the exact same setup reports message latencies in the 100ms range -- the exact same latencies reported if I simply ping my Kafka brokers.

I'll edit this message later with sample code from my producer and consumer along with other details, but I wanted to post something before I forget.

### EDIT, four years later:

I just got an upvote on this, which led me to come back and re-read. Unfortunately (but actually fortunately), I no longer work for that company, and no longer have access to the code I promised I'd share. Kafka has also matured several versions since 0.9.

Another thing I've learned in the ensuing time is that Kafka latencies increase when there is not much traffic. This is due to the way the clients use batching and threading to aggregate messages. It's very fast when you have a continuous stream of messages, but any time there is a moment of "silence", the next message will have to pay the cost to get the stream moving again.

It's been some years since I was deep in Kafka tuning. Looking at the latest version (2.5 -- producer configuration docs [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs)), I can see that they've decreased `linger.ms` (the amount of time a producer will wait before sending a message, in hopes of batching up more than just the one) to zero by default, meaning that the aforementioned cost to get moving again should not be a thing. As I recall, in 0.9 it did not default to zero, and there was some tradeoff to setting it to such a low value. I'd presume that the producer code has been modified to eliminate or at least minimize that tradeoff.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you please post your code?

Comment: I will, but it's going to be a while before I have anything ready to post. Unfortunately I work for an employer who considers source code to be proprietary, so I have to jump through some hoops to get permission. :( I haven't forgotten!

Comment: Do you have an explanation for the 100ms latency when you run it locally? I currently see the same issue and it does not make any sense. Also, what size are your messages?

Comment: As noted above, the 100ms latency is when I run a local client against a remote broker cluster. The ping time to the remote cluster is 97-99ms, so 100ms total latency means Kafka is only taking 1-3ms to respond, which is exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: Sorry got this wrong, thanks for clarifying. I'm currently seeing around 100ms end-to-end latency running broker, producer and consumer on the same machine.

Comment: Does your machine's CPU have enough cores for all three to get attention at the same time?

Try using all default settings for both consumer and producer.

Answer (score 9):

Modern versions of Kafka seem to have pretty minimal latency as the results from [here](https://engineering.linkedin.com/kafka/benchmarking-apache-kafka-2-million-writes-second-three-cheap-machines) show:

2 ms (median)
3 ms (99th percentile)
14 ms (99.9th percentile)

Comment: Linked article is from very old version of Kafka

Answer (score 3):

Kafka can achieve around millisecond latency, by using synchronous messaging. With synchronous messaging, the producer does not collect messages into a patch before sending.

```
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list my_broker_host:9092 --topic test --sync
```

The following has the same effect:

```
--batch-size 1
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the internal producer latency is controlled by linger.ms - i.e., the maximum buffering time. Having a batch-size of 1 simply ignores that timeout, but low latency can be had with any batch size given that linger.ms is set sufficiently low.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using librdkafka as Kafka client library, you must also set `socket.nagle.disable=True`

See https://aivarsk.com/2021/11/01/low-latency-kafka-producers/ for some ideas on how to see what is taking those milliseconds.